# WP7 creating FontFamily and default colors as Static Resource

Tags: windows-phone-7, static, default-value

I would like to setup some default fonts as static resource within my App. Similarly with some colors.

Do I just use a string (defined as an applicationResource (in App.xaml)  or can I actually define a FontFamily and a Color within here.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could define an implicit style to set a default color and font family to use for all TextBlocks like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <Color x:Key="MySpecialColor">#F4811F</Color>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MySpecialColor" Color="{StaticResource MySpecialColor}" />

        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MySpecialColorBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans" />
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

You could then adjust as necessary for specific TextBlocks and add implict styles for other controls if you need to.

Read more at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-Implicit-Styles

You can also use the color or the brush as you need elsewhere, either in XAML or code:

```
(Color)App.Current.Resources["MySpecialColor"];
```

Comment: Thanks - that all makes it a lot clearer.  Just one related query - if I have a color that I want to use throughout the application - and not just  as part of the color scheme of say a TextBlock,  how would I set this up.  I would also need to be able to reference it in the code  behind, as I cannot use binding for the Application Bar.  - Thanks

Comment: @Peter added example use of a color (and brush) as a global resource

Comment: @MattLacey do we need to place it in ResourceDictionary? Because my designer warns that ResourceDictionary must has a key name !?

Comment: @Yamamoto implicit styles work without a key name. That's the point of an implicit style, you don't need to set it explicitly.